# Will Ubuntu be releasing an update for Cedar Trail Processors?

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics

There is a file available on the Intel web site with the file name "cdv-gfx-drivers-1.0.1_bee.tar.bz2" and a date of July 6, 2012. It can be found by searching the [Intel Download Center](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx?lang=eng) for the filename or the string "Linux* PowerVR Graphics/Media Drivers". The download page links to the file, release notes and a link, [Enabling hardware accelerated playback](http://support.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-033648.htm) that takes one to a page containing links to two pdf documents titled "Enabling Hardware Accelerated Playback for Intel® AtomTM Processor N2000/D2000 Series", one for Ubuntu and one for Fedora.

The instruction and release notes speak to working with kernel 3.1.0 and since I do not feel I have the skills, knowledge or training to do anything else but, follow the instructions to the "T", I am very reluctant to try anything on my freshly updated 3.**2**.0 kernel. I would much rather use a Ubuntu supported kernel that applies these drivers and doesn't break anything in the process. Is it a case where this is so new that Canonical has not yet included these drivers but, soon will do so?

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide a specific answer to your question, but LTS-versions of Ubuntu will get newer kernels from time to time. I *think* the idea is that new installs will automatically use the newest kernel, while installing updates will not automatically switch. You'll then have to install the new kernel from the archives.

The first "dot release" (similar to service packs) of 12.04 is scheduled for August 23. I don't know if that will get a kernel upgrade or if that'll wait until 12.04.2 (January 31). I also don't know if your driver will be used.

Comment: Apparently this has been done if my reading of te post at the following link is correct:                                                               https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1025720/comments/10

Comment: That bug is marked Fix Released, which means it was released/fixed/updated.  Note it was released for Precise, because of the 3.2.x kernel, not Quantal and later (which Intel did not test those kernel versions with that package/driver)